# How can I crop an image properly with php?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to crop an image on `PHP`. I saw that there is a function for doing that on `PHP`: [imagecrop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php). Here is the code in which I am trying to crop the image.

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg(//Path of the image);
$croppedImage = imagecrop($image, array("x"=>0,"y"=>0,"width"=>100,"height"=>100));
imagejpeg($croppedImage, //Path in which the image will be stored);
```

Here I want that the crop of the image starts in the left corner of the image and get the values of width and height that I put above.

But it just resize my image, not crop it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried also with the function [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). Here it is what I have tried:

```
dst_image(Destination image link resource) = newImage; //Here the new image that I want to create.

src_image(Source image link resource) = image; //Here the original image.

//Here 0,0 because I want that the new image crop starts in the left corner of the original image.

dst_x(x-coordinate of destination point) = 0;

dst_y(y-coordinate of destination point) = 0;

//Here 0,0 because I want that the crop starts on the 0,0 of the original image

src_x(x-coordinate of source point) = 0;

src_y(y-coordinate of source point) = 0;

dst_w(Destination width) = 150; //The new width of the crop image.

dst_h(Destination height)  = 150; //The new height of the crop image.

src_w(Source width) = 500; //The original width of the image.

src_h(Source height) = 500; //The original height of the image.
```

So finally the function will be like:

```
$b = imagecopyresampled ($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w , $dst_h , $src_w , $src_h );
```

I just have problems in this function it is why avoid the rest (save and imagetruecolor and the rest...)

**This function give to me the result expected but the new image it is black, why?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you've shown us here should give the result you are seeking not the result you describe (provided the image is larger than 100x100). I suggest you review your methodology.

Comment: @symcbean I do not understand what do you mean. Here I put 100x100 as an example (with a bigger image than 100x100) but in my real code I have it dinamically with a variable. Here I just simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution of my problem. I had to put the same value of `dst_w` and `src_w`. The same to `dst_h` and `src_h`. ¡¡And it works!!

The final solution it is the following:

```
$b = imagecopyresampled ($dst_image, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, 150, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$dst_x = 0;   // X-coordinate of destination point
$dst_y = 0;   // Y-coordinate of destination point
$src_x = 100; // Crop Start X position in original image
$src_y = 100; // Crop Srart Y position in original image
$dst_w = 160; // Thumb width
$dst_h = 120; // Thumb height
$src_w = 260; // $src_x + $dst_w Crop end X position in original image
$src_h = 220; // $src_y + $dst_h Crop end Y position in original image

// Creating an image with true colors having thumb dimensions (to merge with the original image)
$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
// Get original image
$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/cropped_whatever.jpg');
// Cropping
imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
// Saving
imagejpeg($dst_image, 'images/crop.jpg');
```

Comment: I used the code that you put here to resize the image but not to crop it.

Comment: Have you tried code I gave? try this code in a test file first

Comment: Can you explain me please why do you do `$src_x + $dst_w`? Because I cannot get the expected result :S

Comment: You mean `$src_w` variable value? `$src_x` is start x position of original image, `$dst_w` is thumb width we want to crop. We need end of x position also hence we did `$src_x + $dst_w` to get end position where we want to stop cropping image.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the imagecrop function of [imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php).

Comment: Yes but I cannot use libraries :(